# Can't start Eclipse 3.5.2?

Tags: java, eclipse, x86, 64-bit, eclipse-3.5

I'm running Windows Vista x64, and I have JDK 1.6.0_21 (x64 version, I believe) installed. I recently downloaded Eclipse 3.5.2 because I want to do some Android development (apparently you can't use 3.6 yet due to bugs...), but I keep running into the same error message whenever I try to start Eclipse:

http://img42.imageshack.us/img42/8282/42786776.jpg

Does anyone know why this is happening? Do I need a 32-bit version of Java or Java 5 or something? If so, how would I specify that Eclipse uses a different version of Java (preferably I'd like to specify it in the eclipse.ini file and not mess with my environment variables).

Comment: As your error says, I don't think you have the good version of java for your windows (x64)

Comment: Did you download the 32 bit or 64 bit version of Eclipse. ? That *has* to match the JDK you have, so make sure whether you have a 32 or 64 bit jdk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a 32 bit VM since you are using a 32 bit eclipse. For 3.5, 64 bit windows builds are hard to find, though I think they do exist.

If your eclipse were a 64 bit version, the launcher would be `org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64`, but yours is `org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86` without the _x64. It is listed around the middle of the error message.

To change the VM, simply add a -vm parameter to your eclipse.ini. I usually add mine as first entry, though I'm not sure that's important. It should look like this:

```
-vm
C:\path\to\java\bin\javaw.exe
```

Comment: You definitely need the version of Eclipse with the same bitness as the JVM.

Comment: Thanks, you are correct. Unfortunately SO is not allowing me to mark this as the accepted solution... :/

Answer (score 0):

Read here http://www.java.com/en/download/faq/java_win64bit.xml and install the version that fits best your version of windows

Comment: The OP already has the 64-bit version of Java installed.  The problem is the 32-bit version of Eclipse that he is trying to run.